# Truncate file names

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to truncate a file of the following format:

> XX Artist - Song(blah blah).mp3

so that only Song.mp3 remains.

Both the Artist and Song may contain spaces and hyphens. I was using split but it didn't work.
Here's my code:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith('.mp3'):
        original = file
        t1 = original.split("(")[0] + ".mp3"
        t2 = t1.split("-")[1]
        t3 = t2.split(" ")[1]
```

Comment: use `split(' - ')`

Comment: how is it supposed to work if there are multiple hyphens ?

Comment: Well, **how** it didn't work?

Comment: it is not obvious what to do when your artist or song name contains `' - '` as well

Comment: `re.match([a-zA-Z0-9]+, fname)`

Comment: It worked. Thanks @AzatIbrakov

Comment: Can you give an existing filename and then what you want out of it ?

Comment: it worked for now, but what to do in edge cases when there are more than 2 parts were obtained with `str.split`?

Comment: what kind of text is your `blah blah`?

Comment: There are no edge cases here. `blah blah` contains the site name `www.example.com`

Comment: Instead of fiddling with the file name, have you considered pulling the song name out of the file's metadata and using that + file extension as your new file name?

Answer (score 2):

Following [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) we can write something like

```
import os

AUDIO_FILES_EXTENSIONS = {'.mp3'}

for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    base_name, extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    if extension in AUDIO_FILES_EXTENSIONS:
        try:
            artist_w_song, _ = file_name.split("(")
            artist, song = artist_w_song.split(" - ")
        except ValueError:
            print('File "' + file_name + '" doesn\'t match the pattern')
            continue
        t3 = song + extension
        # do work
```

It is not a great solution, but at least we are passing through files which doesn't match given file name pattern and if you find out that it doesn't work – return and edit question so we can improve our answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp like this `/- (/w+)\(/`

in Python it will be

```
pattern = re.compile('- (?P<song>\w+)\(')
```

Comment: it doesn't look like **Python** regexp

Comment: It looks like general regexp )))